# How to split a char array into two diferent types in c?

Tags: arrays, c, string, stdin

So, I need to use the stdin to read a file that has two columns, the first one is a char, the second is an integer.

The input file is something like this:

```
i 10
i 20
i 30
i 40
i 50
i 45
r 48
```

My code currently:

```
int main(){
    char line[MAX];
    int n = 0;
    while(fgets(line, MAX, stdin)){
            printf("string is: %s\n",line);

    }
    return 0;
```

The output results in:

```
string is: i 10

string is: i 20

string is: i 30

string is: i 40

string is: i 50

string is: i 45

string is: r 48
```

So, what i need to do now is to assign an char array with the first column and an integer array with the second. Something like **int** V[size] = [10,20,30,40,50,45,48] and **char** W[size] = [i,i,i,i,i,i,r]. How can I do that?

Comment: `sscanf()` should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Use `sscanf` or `strtok`. Also suggest you do some research as there are many many posts on SO and the web in general on how to parse strings in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sscanf()` to parse the string and extract the data you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 500

int main(void)
{
  int num[MAX] = {0}, lines = 0;
  char line[MAX] = {0}, sym[MAX] = {0};

  while (fgets(line, MAX, stdin))
  {
    if (lines >= MAX) /* alternative check comments */
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "arrays full\n");
      break; /* break or exit */
    }

    if (sscanf(line, "%c %d", &sym[lines], &num[lines]) != 2) /* check return value for input error */
    {
      /* handle error */
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    lines++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
  {
    printf("char: %c | num: %d\n", sym[i], num[i]);
  }

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

You may also use `feof()` and `ferror()` to determine if `fgets()` failed or you reached **EOF** .

Comment: Well done. Alternative `while (lines < MAX && fgets(line, MAX, stdin)) { ... }`. Nothing wrong with what you have. Kudos for full validations.

Comment: Thank you! I will add that as a side node.